# Json.NET - Throwing Exception in a property setter during deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net

I use property setters to validate the input in a C# class and throw Exceptions on invalid inputs. I also use Json.NET to deserialize a json to an object. The problem is that I don't know where to catch the exceptions for invalid json values which are thrown by the setters.
The Exception are not thrown from `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method.

```c#
public class A{
    private string a;

    public string number{
        get {return a;}
        set {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(value, "^\\d+$"))
                throw new Exception();
            a = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main()
    {
         // The Exception cannot be caught here.
         A a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>("{number:'some thing'}");
    }    
}
```

Comment: I tired your code and was able to catch the exceptions around the DeserializeObject call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to subscribe to errors while deserializing your object:

```
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>("{number:'some thing'}",
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Error = (sender, args) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
                    args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                }
            });
```

If you remove `args.ErrorContext.Handled = true` statement, exception raised in your setter will be rethrown from `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method. It will be wrapped in `JsonSerializationException` (" Error setting value to 'number' ").

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know why visual studio breaks on `a = value` saying **unhandled exception by user code**. The exception is thrown, but it seems it does not go out of the setter and VS breaks on `a = value`. After pressing `F5` and continue running, the exception is caught properly.

Comment: You might have switched on "Break on exception functionality" of Visual studio. This you can find under Debug->Exception menu.

Comment: @keyr: You are right. I turned it off and now I can catch the excpetion as ValtasarIII said. Thanks a lot.